# Vuforia image Tracking working in Unity-Play but not in Hololens2

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, mrtk

I have created image tracking in Unity(2021.3.0f1) and Vuforia(10.12.3).
I used VUMARK and Barcode to show the hologram.
This is working perfectly fine in Unity-Play mode. But after deploying to Hololens 2, it is failing. I ab able to do other activities like Hand menu etc in Hololens.

I followed Vuforia Hololens Tutorial and other forums with similar topics but failed. I have doubts that I am using an incorrect MRTK profile, but able to figure it out.
Below are Unity Configuration
[image: Working in Unity-Play]

MRTK PRofile
[image]
AR Camera
[image]

Please let me know what mistake I am making.

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Finally, It's Working. I performed 2 below steps.

1. Upgraded Unity Version to 2021.3.16f1
2. Deployed in ARM64 instead of ARM to Hololens.

I do not know Why or how it started to work. But I think deploying to ARM64 did that trick.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After updating Unity on Unity 2021.3.16f1 and my HoloLens on the latest Microsoft Version, it works!